# What is the British version of "jaywalk"?

Tags: phrase-request, british-english

American people say

**jaywalk**: to cross a street carelessly or at an illegal or dangerous place

*The police officer warned us not to jaywalk*

It seems British people don't say "jaywalk".

**Do we have a British version for it?**

Comment: In UK law a pedestrian always has absolute right of way over vehicles.  Even where pedestrians should not be, e.g. Motorways.  Jaywalking does not exist.

Comment: It may not be a legal offence in the UK, but I've known the word since I was a child (for  imprudently walking into the road among traffic).

Comment: @Chenmunka this is specifically not true for motorways, see Highway Code [rule 6 for pedestrians](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/rules-for-pedestrians-1-to-35). More generally the Highway Code never uses the term 'right of way', only 'priority'.

Comment: The term "jaywalking" is mostly understood in the UK, so you can use it obviously, but it's not generally an offence here.  Pedestrians however are generally forbidden from crossing most duel carriageways or motorways (highways).  In the UK pedestrians have priority over traffic, so drivers need to be very careful here. It's a legal requirement.

Comment: @BillyKerr Motorways yes, but dual carriageways are fair game if you want to take the risk.  Some are even crossed by footpaths and bridleways - see for example this [sign on the A11 in Norfolk](https://www.google.com/maps/@52.4471397,0.8433167,3a,75y,44.59h,85.54t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sIYTzmjlWIrNHqmFN0-QyCA!2e0!7i16384!8i8192?entry=ttu)

Comment: @Chris - there's a dual carriageway near where I live on the A1 in Scotland (east coast), it doesn't have motorway status, but the signs clearly forbid pedestrians. It's basically a motorway in all but name, I think only because there's no hard shoulder. Signage will usually tell you what's allowed and where.  Dual carriageways going through the middle of a city/town will likely have some crossing places though.  Also for the driver there are often warning sings to indicate pedestrians might be crossing.

Comment: @BillyKerr The default is that pedestrians are allowed.  Signs forbidding pedestrians are a moderately common exception, and they apply to walking *along* not *across*.  [Here's](https://www.google.com/maps/@51.5039954,-2.5197024,3a,49.9y,93.8h,88.94t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sWMU6Uvde05KMcpjtSHqOUw!2e0!7i16384!8i8192?entry=ttu) a spot on the Bristol Ring road with a "no pedestrians" sign forbidding you from walking east from the bus stop.  But 150m onwards, at the end of the bus lane, a public footpath crosses the road, with a sign pointing across it.  "*Most* dual carriageways" is far from true

Comment: Jaywalking is not about motorways/highwaysw. It's about regular roads/streets in **towns/cities**. And it means that you cross when the **light is red** or where there is no crosswalk.

Comment: It's also not a U.S. law per se but a jurisdictional law that most U.S. states have their own rules on.  For example, in Illinois state law, it's generally not illegal to jaywalk except that the pedestrian must yield right of way to vehicles when not using a marked crosswalk or signal-controlled intersection.  However, county or city laws may have their own restrictions against jaywalking with their own penalties.

Comment: @Lambie but "regular roads in cities" in the US often look a lot like UK A roads in terms of number of lanes etc, and our A roads can go right through cities as well.  They do often have a central barrier, but not always ([US-like example in Cardiff](https://www.google.com/maps/@51.4952689,-3.1432169,3a,75y,195.6h,74.05t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1s617OQfuK7WDd8NvMBMMx5w!2e0!6shttps:%2F%2Fstreetviewpixels-pa.googleapis.com%2Fv1%2Fthumbnail%3Fpanoid%3D617OQfuK7WDd8NvMBMMx5w%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D54.371212%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i16384!8i8192?entry=ttu))

Comment: @ChrisH Sure, sure. My distinction is better roads/streets and motorways/highways. No one seemed to be making the distinction when I posted my first comment above...

Comment: "Jaywalking" was a marketing push by early automobile manufacturers to try to make their products be viewed as less deadly by attempting to create a public perception that pedestrians were to blame for their own deaths ("jay" being a derogatory term akin to how "country hick" might be used today, positing that people who didn't affirmatively give way to vehicles were from less-cultured areas). The campaign has been problematic from the beginning.

Comment: @ChrisH: FYI, the AmE term for the "central barrier" (at least if it's grass instead of concrete) is "median".  Except in New Orleans where it's the "neutral ground".

Comment: @dan04 "median" is better translated as "central reservation", which may or may not include a safety barrier or a fence

Comment: There is a perhaps surprising political context to the law because it is mostly enforced against minorities. The details of what legally constitutes jaywalking (distance from nearest safe crossing, one or both nearest crossings with crosswalk etc.) are complicated. In many places, people jaywalk all the time, but only some are fined or even arrested -- 3.7 times as many Black people than White. From my European perspective I also note the dissonance with the self-label "Land of the Free", a dissonance which occurs in other respects as well.

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: Is that a national average, or within specific cities?  One major confounding factor is that White people are more likely to live in car-dependent suburbs and not walk for transportation at all, whereas Black people to live in inner cities with more pedestrian/vehicle conflicts and more police per acre.

Comment: @dan04 LA. San Diego: 4.3. From https://www.nytimes.com/2022/10/26/us/california-jaywalking-decriminalized.html.

Answer (score 19):

I suppose there is not a British version. My understanding is that there is no such offense in the UK. You might find this [BBC article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/magazine/6251431.stm) interesting.

Comment: There is absolutely not a British offence equivalent to the US 'jaywalking'. We look with bemusement (and horror) at the Americans and their whistle blowing cops telling people where they can or cannot walk.

Comment: I remember at the 1981 World Science Fiction Convention in Denver, CO, some British fans were ticketed for jaywalking: they had no idea that they were not permitted to cross the road except at a marked crossing.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: You're right that there's no such offence in Britain, but there is in the UK - it does exist in Northern Ireland. I'm not sure if there's a specific term used for it there, though.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey There are at least some pedestrian laws in the UK. For example, it’s illegal to walk on a motorway except in emergencies: https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/rules-for-pedestrians-1-to-35

Comment: I gave a similar answer to a broader question a few years ago. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/43535/do-other-countries-guarantee-freedoms-that-the-united-states-does-not-have/43566#43566

Comment: I remember some obscure book explaining how jay-walking was an American-only propaganda campaign, but there it is in lowly Wikipedia "Automobile interests in the US took up the cause of labeling and scorning jaywalkers in the 1910s and early 1920s."

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: To be fair, the offense barely exists in the US. It has occasionally been used as a pretext or means of discrimination, but in practice, you're not likely to get ticketed for jaywalking unless you're making a nuisance of yourself (e.g. standing in the middle of the street and deliberately obstructing traffic).

Comment: @Kevin I remember, years ago, walking in the Midwest with some native Californians. They were puzzled, then shocked, when I started a midway crossing of an empty street. Apparently in CA jaywalking was strictly enforced.

Comment: @OwenReynolds: I live in CA, and I have no idea what you are talking about. People will usually cross at the crossing if there is one, but they jaywalk all the damn time.

Comment: @Kevin In Los Angeles, jaywalking is *occasionally* enforced and seemed to be frowned upon by the very small proportion of Angelenos who ever walk anywhere. It's definitely a different culture from Washington DC or New York where jaywalking is kind of expected and drivers have to be very careful if they don't want to hit anyone. There was a downtown jaywalking sting that lasted several days and was mentioned on the news when I lived in L.A. That's the only time I've ever heard of anyone actually getting a ticket for jaywalking.

Comment: Asked a cop friend of mine about enforcement of that particular "crime" here in Tulsa, since I've crossed whereever my whole life and never got hassled for it. I was told it's mostly used as a tool to be able to arrest the homeless/vagrants. Selective Enforcement FTW!

Answer (score 11):

As others have said, there is no specific law governing crossing the road in the UK, so there is no clear equivalent. The emphasis in both education and the law is on crossing *safely*.

The [Highway Code](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/the-highway-code/rules-for-pedestrians-1-to-35) (and the separate [Highway Way Code for Northern Ireland](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/rules-pedestrians-1-35)) lists both *laws* and *guidance* for all road users, including pedestrians. Rule 6 is that "Pedestrians MUST NOT be on motorways or slip roads except in an emergency" and Rule 18 includes "You MUST NOT loiter on any type of crossing". The capitalised "must not" refers to laws enforcing that prohibition, which are referenced in the text.

Rule 7, which covers crossing other roads; and rules 18 to 30, which cover types of marked crossing; are guidance only - they don't contain or reference strict definitions, or specific offenses. Note that crossing the road *dangerously* could still constitute an offence, on a case by case basis; as the introduction to the Highway Code clarifies:

> Although failure to comply with the other rules of the Code will not, in itself, cause a person to be prosecuted, The Highway Code may be used in evidence in any court proceedings under the Traffic Acts.

Most people in the UK will be familiar with this guidance as the "Green Cross Code", which is taught to children.

Some might recognise the word "jaywalking", some might associate it particularly with other countries, and some might never have heard it. I seem to recall first hearing it in an American context, and having to look up what it meant.

To be sure you'll be understood, just be descriptive, and say "crossing the road dangerously". If you're referring to it in the context of the USA or another country where it has a legal definition, "jaywalking" should be considered untranslateable, perhaps with an explanation in parentheses if it's important.

Comment: Not quite true to say it doesn't exist in the _UK_, because a relevant law does exist in Northern Ireland. There's none in GB though :)

Comment: @psmears Huh, today I learned that NI has its own Highway Code (but England, Wales, and Scotland share one). However, [the same section in the NI Code](https://www.nidirect.gov.uk/articles/rules-pedestrians-1-35) does not appear to include any additional "must" wording or law references, which is surprising if such a law exists.

Comment: Apparently it's the [Road Traffic (Northern Ireland) Order 1995, section 38](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/nisi/1995/2994/article/38) - "If a pedestrian through his own negligence on a road endangers his own safety, or that of any other person, he is guilty of an offence."

Comment: @psmears That's not a prohibition of jaywalking specifically, just of general dangerous behaviour. Failure to follow the Green Cross Code could be used as evidence of such negligence, but would not automatically consitute an offense if nobody was endangered. (I've added a quote from the Highway Code that mentions this distinction.) In contrast, a jaywalking prohibition would make it an offense *in itself* to cross the road in certain places, regardless of whether it could be demonstrated to be unsafe to do so in that specific instance.

Comment: That kinda depends on your exact definition of what constitutes "jaywalking". The law is enough for it to be included on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaywalking), for what it's worth (and no, I didn't edit that page ;-) ).

Comment: @psmears Right, I think Wikipedia is a bit misleading there; I'm pretty sure near-identical wording could be found in laws applying to England, Wales, and Scotland. The actual offense is just the pedestrian equivalent of "dangerous driving", not a specific "jaywalking" offense. It may be that it is more pro-actively enforced by the Police Service of Northern Ireland, using that law as a basis, but there's no citation actually making that distinction.

Comment: @IMSoP — it is my understanding that very few paved roads connect Northern Ireland to the rest of the UK, so maybe that is why they have a separate Highway Code.

Answer (score 7):

As a child growing up in Britain, I was certainly told never to "jaywalk", meaning "walk into a road recklessly or aimlessly".

However, "jaywalking" would not normally have any suggestion of illegality when used here, any more than "running with scissors" might.

Comment: The instruction was of course common, but the word *jaywalk* wasn't (for example I can't find it in any materials from the [Green Cross Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Cross_Code).

Comment: @ChrisH: I grew up in London in the ’80s, and exactly like this answer, I learned *jaywalk* with that meaning.  I knew it as a completely informal term — so I’m not at all surprised that it’s not in the official material you link — but with no particularly American associations.

Comment: @ChrisH I heard it used informally by parents and teachers, but I don't think I ever saw it written down back then. (I'm a similar age to PLL but from a different part of the country.)

Comment: @PLL I grew up in the South East in the ’70s and ’80s, and I don't think I ever heard the word used — at least, not outside of US TV programmes.  Of course, all children are taught not to cross roads without due care and attention; but even the Green Cross Code told you simply to ‘find a safe place to cross’ (now ‘…the _safest_ place…’), without specifying that some places might not be _permissible_.

Comment: @PLL in a similar time and place to you, I didn't.  but we didn't watch much American TV in our house

Answer (score 5):

You can just use "jaywalk" and most people will understand what you mean, even if it's not a concept in British society.

[Australia](https://www.news.com.au/lifestyle/real-life/news-life/police-are-cracking-down-on-jaywalking-after-a-spike-in-pedestrian-accidents/news-story/23273b3bc1c0fb080dbf35d7d1339aaf) and [Hong Kong](https://www.scmp.com/comment/opinion/article/3231292/jaywalking-crackdown-not-enough-make-hong-kong-safer-city-all) penalize crossing the road outside designated crossing areas. Both jurisdictions' usage of English is heavily influenced by British English. Both commonly use "jaywalk" to describe such behaviour.

Comment: In my experience in Australia, jaywalking most commonly refers to crossing a road diagonally, instead of taking the shortest path across the road.

Answer (score 4):

As Edmond said, there is no specific British word for jaywalking, and it is not a crime (or even a legal concept) in the UK. However, if you must use a word for such an act, you can use either the word 'jaywalking' itself or 'illegally crossing a road'. In informal contexts, I've also seen the term 'jumping the street' get used.

Comment: Jaywalking is commonly used in British sources discussing the US, as in the BBC article linked above.

Comment: I learned the expression from my mother, who had no American connections, in the 1950s, so it's not true that it 'isn't a concept in the UK'.

Comment: @KateBunting - it was common enough in my childhood in the 1950s. I learned it from books, films, TV shows, etc.

Comment: That's right. British people do tend understand the meaning of the term. However, when I said "concept", I meant to refer to the non-existence of the idea of jaywalking in the laws of UK. Jaywalking cannot happen because it doesn't exist according to the law. But I should clarify that.

Answer (score 1):

A simple search of the British-English corpus shows that "jaywalk" and its inflections are used frequently, albeit not at as high a rate as in the American-English corpus: [Comparison of the use of inflections of "jaywalk" in the American and British English corpora](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jaywalk_INF%3Aeng_us_2019%2Cjaywalk_INF%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1900&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3)

The editorialization of the other answers regarding the supposed inconceivability of this simple concept to the British mind is irrelevant.

Comment: I can't speak for anyone else, but my answer is not suggesting that it is "inconceivable", only that the specific meaning of "jaywalking" - crossing at a _non-designated_ place - is not one that comes up often in the UK, since the emphasis of road safety education is on crossing _safely_, not crossing _in approved places_. I can only speak anecdotally, and others may have other experience, but I would never use the word myself, and would be surprised to hear it outside an American or other non-British context.

Comment: Plotting your ngram search as a ratio does suggest it's becoming more common in the UK, though, at least according to Google's corpus labelling: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jaywalking%3Aeng_gb_2019+%2F+jaywalking%3Aeng_us_2019&year_start=1920&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3